# Understanding how certificates work in a client-server interaction

Tags: https, cryptography, certificate, tls1.2

So, I'm trying to understand how certificates really, really work - I haven't been able to find what exactly I'm looking for on google so I'm phrasing it my way... If there's a straightforward link that you think might help me - please post it and I will delete this question.

I understand that when the client(say, a browser) makes a request to a website, it verifies the identity of the website by checking its certificate. Self signed certificates are discouraged and certificates from the Certificate Authority (and its branches) are the real deal. Now that the identity has been verified, the request is processed by the server and the response is sent to the client and now the user (a human being) can see that green lock sign on their browser next to the URL. Did I sum this up correctly? And this response is encrypted and will be decrypted by the browser/client?

In the case of SSO (single sign on) flows - when SAML assertions are "digitally signed" - what exactly does this mean? And how does the above mentioned certificates help in that?

I've just got too many concepts all mixed up in my head and was looking for clarity understanding systems and security and TLS.

Comment: You're close on use of certificates for HTTPS (the web) and other SSL/TLS except there is not _one_ Certificate Authority but several independent ones -- [5 currently are most widely used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) but browser or OS truststores usually have ~100. The canonical answers for SSL/TLS are [over on security.SX](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/) where this is more on-topic. For the web once an HTTPS (or WebRTC) connection is made and secured, there may be _multiple_ requests and responses. ...

Comment: ... SSO and SAML are completely different things and not related to SSL/TLS, although they may use the same technology standards for certs. If you have more specific questions about them, security.SX probably is appropriate for those also.

Comment: And for each and every subsequent requests and responses, is the certificate verified every time?

Comment: That's up to the relying party(ies), which is normally only the client=browser, although I suspect _most_ only check at the handshake. However, connections _usually_ are kept idle only a short time -- maybe a few minutes. That could still allow tens or hundreds or requests per connection, especially with modern web designs, and within that timeframe validity isn't much of any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is all about asymmetric cryptography. This allows to encrypt the message with one key and decrypt with another. Why is this helpful.

**Secure interaction**

You can send a message to your server using the public key of that server. Thus you can be sure that nobody else (except of that server) would be able to decrypt that message

**Digital signing**

You can encrypt a digest of a message with your private key and anyone will be able to check if that was you by decrypting your "signature" with your public key.

**At what stage the certificate is involved**

Both above cases have a pitfall. You cannot be really sure that the public key that the server provides you is really a key of the party you trust to. The same with signatures. You cannot be sure that the public key you have just successfully used to verify a signature is really a key of a person you expect to sign your contract.

Certificate is a bundle of a public key and the information about the holder of the key pair. This bundle is digitally signed with the private key of CA.

**What is the end to end process**

Let's consider https case. Your client says to a server "Hey I want to use https protocol". This is the point where asymmetric cryptography is involved. You use server's public key to encrypt a symmetric key (since the asymmetric cryptography is somewhat expensive, it is used only when symmetric key is being negotiated) that will be used for encrypting traffic.

But how can you be sure you can trust that server. Actually what server sends you is not just a key but a certificate. You take the certificate and verify that the server name specified in the cert is actually what you used in your address bar. You also verify the signature of CA using that CA's public key.

**Certification chain**

Public key of CA that has signed the server certificate might also require verification. Such verification is performed in the same way as explained above. The chain has to eventually stop at the certificate that you absolutely trust. Such certificates are stored at so called **trust store**.

So this is how ssl works. Digitally signed SAML assertions work in the very similar way. They deliver certificates which you can validate and use the public keys extracted from them for validating the signature of assertions.

Comment: I see! So what happens is when I generate a SAML assertion and I sign it - I sign it using my private key, right? And in the assertion I include the public key information? So when the service provider receives this public key information and the digest, it decrypts using the public key information and asserts the validity. 

Did I get understand this correctly? I guess my pain point is understanding how the encryption/decryption works when the private key is only known to one party and how does the other party "figure it out" and decrypt :)

Comment: If we're talking about signatures you can think of private key as of a password that is used for encryption (you store it at your secured place) and of public key as of a password that is used for decryption (everyone can have it). So in SAML you sign assertion with your private key and provide certificate that contains your public key (since it is not secret).

Comment: Client validates the certificate (either look for it in its trust store or verifies that CA that signed the certificate has its certificate in client's trust store), if it's okay it takes that key (aka public password for decryption), computes the digest of a message, then decrypts encrypted digest (aka signature) of a message and compare two values. If they are identical, then it considers the message was really signed by certificate holder.. Regarding what particular math underlies asymmetric cryptography I'm afraid I won't be able to clearly explain. Refer to RSA algorithm description.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't looking for the math behind it, just trying to understand the process. Going by your explanation, certificate verification is a different process and occurs before they key is validated, am I right?

Comment: You mean before signature is validated? Yes. First of all the certificate has to be validated. Otherwise there is no trust for the entire thing. You can read more about certificate validation here http://www.oasis-pki.org/pdfs/Understanding_Path_construction-DS2.pdf